# When a group-like algebraic structure is actually a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, functional-equations

Consider the following group-like algebraic structure (don't know its name).

Let $G$ be a non-empty set with a **partial** binary operation $*:G \times G \rightarrow G$ (i.e. $*$ is not necessarily defined for all possible pairs of elements from $G \times G$) such that the following conditions hold:

1. *Identity*: there exists an identity element $e \in G$ such that for every $a \in G$ $e*a$ and $a*e$ are defined and $e*a=a*e=a$.
2. *Inverse*: for each $a \in G$ there exists an element $a^{-1} \in G$ such that $a*a^{-1}$ and $a^{-1}*a$ are defined and $a*a^{-1}=a^{-1}*a=e$.
3. *Restricted associativity*: for each $a,c \in G$ there exists $b \in G$ such that $(a*b)*c$ and $a*(b*c)$ are defined and $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$.

I am interested in: (A) conditions under which $(G,*)$ is actually a group, (B) conditions under which this structure can be extended to a group on $G$.

Any references will be very much appreciated.

**Update**. Let me introduce the context under which the structure is appeared.

I am trying to solve the transitivity functional equation of the form $u(s,s')=H(u(s,s'),u(s',s''))$, $s,s',s'' \in S$ under the condition $u(s,s)=u(s',s')$ for any $s,s' \in S$.

Here $S$ is a set, $u:S \times S \rightarrow R$ is an unknown function, and $H:u(S,S) \times u(S,S) \rightarrow u(S,S)$ is an unknown partial function.
This functional equation is related to the above structure if we put $G:=u(S,S)$, $*:=H$, $e:=u(s,s)$, $a^{-1}=u(s',s)$, where $s,s' \in S$ are such that $u(s,s')=a$, and $a*b$ is defined if and only if there exists a triple $s,s',s'' \in S$ such that $a=u(s,s')$, $b=u(s',s'')$.

I am interested in the case when $(G,*)$ actually constitutes a group, since in this case the equation considered reduces to the Sincov functional equation whose general solution is known.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us a context, why this particular kind of structures to consider? Especially condition 3 seems somewhat unusual (and seems  redundant: you can always choose $b:=e$).

Comment: Your condition 3 is incredibly weak. In particular, it's an immediate consequence of 1: take $b=e$. By contrast, in a group associativity is required to hold *everywhere*; I think the right condition instead is "Whenever $a*(b*c)$ is defined, then so is $(a*b)*c$, and they are equal; and similarly with $a*(b*c)$ and $(a*b)*c$ swapped." Alternately, a slightly weaker form of this would be "Whenever $a*(b*c)$ and $(a*b)*c$ are each defined, they are equal."

Comment: For example, for $x\in X$, let $*_{X, x}$ be the binary operation defined by: if $a\not=x$ and $b\not=x$, then $a*_{X, x}b=x$; meanwhile, $a*_{X, x}x=x*_{X, x}a=a$ for all $a\in X$ (including $a=x$). This *total* relation always satisfies your axioms (taking $e=x$ for (1) and $b=x$ for (3)), but is about as far from being a group as it is possible to be.

Comment: If you want a group-like structure with partial operation, look up *groupoids*: these are categories where all arrows are invertible.

Comment: We can not choose $b:=e$ in Condition 3, whenever $a*c$ is not defined.